# android sdk translated edittext affects functionality

Tags: android, sdk, textview, behavior, animated

I'm having an edittext inside a relative layout which is being translated. When the layout is translated (and the editext is still visible), it does not get updated anymore, so when i'm typing something in it I don't see the edittext with the new content. Also, for activating the keyboard I have to click on the space the edittext was initially located before the animation, though the edittext is translated ,rendered and visible where it should be.

Comment: please post the code what u have created